# Is there a way to strip digits before the decimal place from a float using f-string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, f-string

I'm trying to solve the following challenge:

Write a function that takes a *float* and two integers (*before* and *after*). The function should return a float consisting of *before* digits before the decimal place and *after* digits after. Thus, if we call the function with `1234.5678, 2, 3` the return value should be `34.567`

I have a version that works without `f-strings` as it stands, and I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing it using `f-strings` instead.

```
def eitherSide(someFloat, before, after)  :
    bits  = str(someFloat).split('.')
    bit1 = bits[0][:-before]
    bit2 = bits[1][:after]
    num = float(bit1 + '.' + bit2)
    return print(num)
```

Thanks!

Comment: ```return print(num)```? This will return```None```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it would make mathematical sense to strip digits from the integer part of a float.
but fstring allow you to format the decimal part easily with something like `print(f"{value:.3f}")`

if you really want to use fstring you could do :

```py
def eitherSide(someFloat, before, after)  :
    left, right = str(someFloat).split('.')
    return f"{left[-before:]}.{right[:after]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using some math and f-strings:

```
def eitherSide(someFloat, before, after):
    return f"{someFloat % 10**before:.{after}f}"
    # return float(f"{sf:.{after}f}")  
    # seems weird to possibly lose the representation again
```

This will however, not truncate, but round.